# ¿Cómo cambiar los estilos de PrimeNG Calendar?

Tags: angular, calendar, primeng

Intento cambiar el tamaño del calendario y del input mediante las propiedades styleClass y inputStyleClass, tal y como dice [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38265324/primeng-calendar-bug-when-applying-css-class-from-bootstrap) y siguiendo la [documentación](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar). Pero no consigo que cambie nada.

html donde llamo al componente:

```
<div id="fechaNacimiento">
            <span class="text1">Fecha nacimiento</span>
            <prime-datepicker-popup ></prime-datepicker-popup>
</div>
```

template del componente:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateIn" showIcon="true"
    styleClass="primeNgCalendar" inputStyleClass="primeNgCalendarInput">
</p-calendar>
```

component:

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'prime-datepicker-popup',
  templateUrl: '../../primeDatePicker-popup.html',
  styleUrls:['../../comuns.css']
})
...
```

css intento 1:

```
.primeNgCalendarInput.ui-inputtext{
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;;

}
```

css intento 2

```
 .ui-inputtext{
        width: 50px;
        height: 100px;;

    }
```

Edit 1:
poniendo los estilos en el styles.css que se encuentra en la raiz del proyecto (src/styles.css) tampoco va.

```
/*intento 1*/
.primeNgCalendar .ui-calendar .ui-calendar-w-btn{
    background-color: black;
}
/*intento 2*/
.primeNgCalendar .ui-calendar{
    background-color: black;
}
/*intento 3*/
.primeNgCalendar .ui-calendar-w-btn{
    background-color: black;
}
/*intento 4*/
.primeNgCalendar{
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que los estilos de Angular sólo afectan al componente en el que se declaran, por tanto si tienes un componente A que usa al componente B, los estilos que declares en A no afectan a B.

En tu caso B es un componente cuyo código no es tuyo, por tanto no lo puedes modificar, pero hay otra forma de modificar el estilo: usando el fichero styles.css que está en la raíz de tu proyecto. Los estilos que añadas ahí se aplicarán a toda la aplicación.

Comment: Poniendo los etilos en style.css de la raiz del proyecto no funciona. Tambien intenté quitar p-calendar del componente que creé , poniendolo directamente en el html, aun nada.

Comment: ¿directamente en el HTML? ¿qué quieres decir?

Comment: Sin usar el componente creado por mi, poniendo  <p-calendar ...></p-calendar> donde quiero que aparezca el calendario. En la documentación he notado que algunas properties las pone entre [ ] y otras no. ¿A qué se debe? No lo dice...

Comment: Eso es propio de la sintaxis de Angular y da para otra pregunta

Answer (score -2):

```
::ng-deep {
  .ui-inputtext{
     width: 50px;
     height: 100px;;

  }
 }
```

Comment: Se considera de baja calidad una respuesta que contiene sólo código, explica lo que haz hecho